# Convert GUID string to octetBytes using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, guid

I have a powershell script which outputs all Exchange 2003 mailboxes by size.

```
$computers = "vexch01","vexch02"
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
  Get-Wmiobject -namespace root\MicrosoftExchangeV2 -class Exchange_Mailbox -computer $computer | sort-object -desc Size | select-object MailboxDisplayName,StoreName,@{Name="Size/Mb";Expression={[math]::round(($_.Size / 1024),2)}}, MailboxGUID | Export-Csv -notype -Path $computer.csv 
}
```

Currently this outputs the MailboxGUID as a string type GUID (e.g. {21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}).  I want to look up users in AD by this, but AD stores them in octetBytes format.

I have found some [powershell functions](http://www.leadfollowmove.com/archives/powershell/converting-a-guid-string-to-octet-string) which will do the conversion but only when the curly braces are removed.  The [Guid.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/560tzess.aspx) method should supply this, but I can't get it to work in the above.

However, if I could figure out how to do that, the [Guid.ToByteArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tobytearray.aspx) method might get me even closer.

Has anyone cracked this?

Update: the answers so far helped me write a function that converts the mailboxguid into the correct format for searching via LDAP.  However, I now cannot get this working in the script.  This is my updated script:

```
function ConvertGuidToLdapSearchString(
    [parameter(mandatory=$true, position=0)]$Guid
)
{
    $guid_object = [System.Guid]$Guid
    ($guid_object.ToByteArray() | foreach { '\' + $_.ToString('x2') }) -join ''
}

# Gets data through WMI from specified Exchange mailbox servers
$servers = "vexch01","vexch02"
foreach ($server in $servers) {
  Get-Wmiobject -namespace root\MicrosoftExchangeV2 -class Exchange_Mailbox -computer $computer | sort-object -desc Size | select-object MailboxDisplayName,StoreName,@{Name="Size/Mb";Expression={[math]::round(($_.Size / 1024),2)}}, @{Name="LDAP Guid";Expression={ConvertGuidToLdapSearchString(MailboxGUID)}} | Export-Csv -notype -Path $server.csv 
}
```

I'm not sure why using the function in the `select-object` with `@{Name="LDAP Guid";Expression={ConvertGuidToLdapSearchString(MailboxGUID)}}` doesn't work.

Is there another way of using this function in `select-object` that will give the string?

Comment: I updated my answer with more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In conjunction with Andy Schneider's answer, you may find this function useful:

```
function Convert-GuidToLdapSearchString(
    [parameter(mandatory=$true, position=0)][guid]$Guid
)
{
    ($Guid.ToByteArray() | foreach { '\' + $_.ToString('x2') }) -join ''
}
```

(I thought I had a more clever way to do this by adding a ScriptProperty to System.Guid, but I seem to have learned that you can't effectively add members to structs.)

I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish based on your comment, but I think you may have just left out a $_.  Here is a somewhat contrived example that creates an object with a property that is a GUID, then uses select and Convert-GuidToLdapSearchString to convert the format.  I hope it helps.

```
$o = New-Object PSObject -Property @{ GUID = $([Guid]::NewGuid()) }
$o
$o | select @{ Name='SearchString'; Expression={ Convert-GuidToLdapSearchString $_.GUID } }
```

This is not at all how I had imagined the function being used.  I expected you would use it to create an LDAP search clause such as:

```
$searchString = Convert-GuidToLdapSearchString '{9e76c48b-e764-4f0c-8857-77659108a41e}'
$searcher = [adsisearcher]"(msExchMailboxGuid=$searchString)"
$searcher.FindAll()
```

Comment: That is extremely useful.  I have managed to apply this to a single GUID, and it does indeed return it in the correct manner, in a very simple way.  However, I am not sure how to incorporate this into my script.  I have declared the function at the top of the script, but when I call it with `select-object @{Name="LDAP Guid";Expression={ConvertGuidToLdapSearchString(MailboxGUID)}}` I don't get any output in the CSV file.  I guess I am getting down to some basic PowerShell stuff here - any pointers?

Comment: I'd vote you up again if I could.  Thanks - this cracked it!  You are right - this needs to go into a search clause so I can get the username associated with each mailbox.  One step at a time...

Answer (score 1):

Are you casting the string to a GUID ?

```
$guid = [System.Guid]"{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
$guid.ToString()
$guid.ToByteArray()
```